# unable to add SSRadioButtonsController radio button title from code

Tags: ios, swift

i'm using https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController . when i add radio buttons through storyboard and set titles it works fine but when i try to add set title of radio button through code it doesn't work.

class ViewController: UIViewController, SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate {

var radioButtonController: SSRadioButtonsController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()


let radioButton = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20 ))
radioButton.circleRadius = 8
radioButton.setTitle("male", forState: .Normal)

let radioButton1 = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 20, height: 20 ))
radioButton.circleRadius = 8
radioButton.setTitle("female", forState: .Highlighted)

self.view.addSubview(radioButton)
self.view.addSubview(radioButton1)

buttonArray.append(radioButton)
buttonArray.append(radioButton1)

radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: buttonArray)
radioButtonController!.delegate = self
radioButtonController!.shouldLetDeSelect = true

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

func didSelectButton(aButton: UIButton?) {
print(aButton)
    }


}
```

Comment: your button corner radius is working or not

Comment: yes it's working fine.

Comment: change the frame of button and try once ...

Comment: frame means change the width like change `20` to `150`

Comment: Found the solution  by default button title was white  i changed it     radioButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal).
thanks for look into this.

Comment: @ha ha , welcome my bro, I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by default button title was white i changed it with black and it is working fine

```
radioButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```